# Rotate images by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to rotate an image 90 degrees, 180 degrees and 360 degrees on button click.

```
 <img class="test" id="image" src="images/image" alt="This is the Display Image" />
```

I have used this script and I don't liked it because it just displays one single rotation...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#image').rotate({maxAngle:25,minAngle:-55,
      bind: [
        {"mouseover":function(){$(this).rotateAnimation(85); } },
        {"mouseout":function(){$(this).rotateAnimation(-35); } }
      ]
   });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var img = $('img');
    if(img.hasClass('north')){
        img.attr('class','west');
    } else if(img.hasClass('west')){
        img.attr('class','south');
    } else if(img.hasClass('south')){
        img.attr('class','east');
    } else if(img.hasClass('east')){
        img.attr('class','north');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JkHqa/

** Look at the JQuery animate function if you want to incorporate animation

Comment: Ehh... I'm a mac developer and tend to not work around IE a whole lot... Try looking into which functions ie has an issue with (`hasClass` or  `attr`) and see if there are work arrounds (might be able to use `attr(classname)` instead of `hasClass(classname)` if thats the issue or their might be a `.class()` you can use instead of `attr('class', value)`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this I hope it will help.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaUJm/)

**HTML**

```
<img class="test" id="image" src="http://fbhunt.com/images/FBHUNT200.png" alt="This is the Display Image" />

<input type="button" value="click" id="clickme">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#clickme',function(){
        $("#image").css({'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use CSS 3 also to achieve the same goal

```
#div:focus
{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

Comment: I want this on clicking a button and i want to rotate the images in all sides..Do u have any idea for this?

Comment: You can use CSS 3 Animations (For Multiple rotations) >>
style.display = 'none' >> function show ()
 {
  document.getElementById("thing").style.display = "inline";
 } > change it to inline on click!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ I hope this will help you.